# Windows 7 seeing perpetual "Shutdown to update"

Tags: windows-7, windows-update, shutdown

For about a week I've been seeing the yellow shield with an exclamation point on my shutdown button. I shutdown but no updates are applied and shortly afterward the yellow shield appears again. I see no recent update failures and the only thing I can think it is, that I keep saying "not yet" to the Windows 10 automatic install/update.

Does anyone know? Has MS gone this far and is now nagging me to "finish" the windows 10 update by showing me the "pending update" on my shutdown button?

I've had updates fail in the past and have always been able to correct them, but this one is like a "failure" that's not really complaining about anything, but yet the "pending update" remains.

Thanks

Mike

Answer (score 0):

Are you checking for failures in the event log, or are you saying you're not seeing notification popups that indicate failures? I would start by checking the event viewer to see what's happening with Windows Update during those times, as that should give you a more verbose explanation as to what's going on. (To get to that log: Start Button > Run > type "eventvwr.exe" > Expand "Windows Logs" > Highlight "Setup").

Then on the right side of the screen, look at all of the recent entries and see if you find any failures there. Specifically, it might help to look at what's happening around the times that you see notifications reappear, and also during times where the computer is shutting down.